# winding number, "function degree"

Tags: algebraic-topology

> For every continuous function $f: S^1\to S^1$ with $f(1)=1$ we define the "function degree" $deg(f)$ as winding number of the path $f\circ w_1$
>
> Show, that:
>
> a) $deg(f)=n\Leftrightarrow f\circ w_1\sim w_n$
>
> b) If $deg(f)=1$ then is $f\sim id$ is a homotopy
>
> c) Are $f,g$ continuous functions with $f(1)=g(1)=1$, then holds $deg(f\circ g)=deg(f)deg(g)$

Hello,

I have a couple of questions to this task.

a)

I want to show, that $deg(f)=n\Leftrightarrow f\circ w_1\sim w_n$

But I am not sure, what is meant by $w_1$ and $w_n$. 
Are these just random paths with winding number 1 and winding number n?
Does the explicit path not matter?

I have to give a homotopy $H$, such that $f\circ w_1\sim_H w_n$.
I do not know, how to do this unfortunalty, and might need some help.

Thanks in advance for your clarification of this task and hints.

Comment: I think that $w_n: [0,1] \to S^1$ denotes the path $t \mapsto e^{2 \pi i nt}$.

Comment: Yes, I actually think that too, but was not sure. Does that mean, that $w_1:[0,1]\to S^1$ denotes the path $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$

Comment: Yes, it does. It's the case $n=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also have a hint on how to solve a)?

Comment: It depends on your definition of winding number. I know a definition which is basically "a path $p$ has winding number $n$ if and only if $p \sim w_n$", so that a) follows by definition. What is your definition?

Comment: We defined "winding number" as follows: $w, \tilde{w}$ paths and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, where $\tilde{w}$ is the lift of $w$ to the startingpoint $t$, then the winding number of $w$ is $W(w):=\tilde{w}(1)-\tilde{w}(0)$